# changing products urls - redirects

Tags: wp-redirect, sitemap

I created my website without not knowing much about seo. I am editing my products pages with yoast, and I am changing products urls. My site is new, I have just indexed it in google search console, I haven't have visits yet as I am still perfecting it. Do I need to 301 redirect to the new urls? Or that is just for sites already ranking? Do I need to resubmit my sitemaps to google web console after I am finished editing my site? I am not sure how to procede.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to 301 redirect to the new urls?

You only need 301 redirects if you have an old site, or old urls that you would like forwarded over to new pages.

For instance:

```
site.com/oldurl -> site.com/newurl
oldsite.com/oldurl -> newsite.com/newurl
```

With your site being new, I would believe this isn't something critical for you to concern yourself with.

> Do I need to resubmit my sitemaps to google web console after I am finished editing my site?

As long as google has the link to the sitemap in Google Web Console, once you update, google will eventually crawl your site and update.